# Proving an angle inside a cube is $90°$

Tags: geometry

[image]

Point $I$ is the midline of segment $BF$ and point $J$ is the midline of segment $AC$. I would like to prove that angle $HJI$ is $90°$. I have proven it through calculations algrebaically. But I want to know if we can prove it geometrically? Like, maybe we can know it is $90°$ from other angles? Thank you.

Comment: It wasn't probably a very good idea to fill the cube with blue painting. Makes things harder to distinguish...

Comment: @DonAntonio I apologize, I didn't know how to change the colour of the planes. But I just found out how to do that. Shoul I change the illustration? How can I make it easier to distinguish??

Comment: Put a link to the new diagram and let us check whether it is clearer or not, before you even try to change the question itself.

Comment: I think it's better to leave away the lines AC, CI, and AI.

Comment: How about this one? https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YoZAe3F33xgT5sx4IpfwUGoFn2XBrVSn/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: It does not matter anymore, dude. You have 3 answers already. :o) But  yeah, looks good.

Comment: @amsmath lol so sorry I was too late :')

Comment: @user566922 by algebraic methods do you mean thebuse of coordinates and dot product or something different?

Comment: @gimusi I used pythagorean theorem by instancing the cube's side with a whole number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an easy proof using vectors. Assuming the vertical axis is the $\;z\,-$ axis, the horizontal rightbound axis is the **positive** $\;x\,-$ axis, and the horizontal leftbound axis is the **positive** $\;y\,-$ axis (the positiveness is just for simplicity), we then have the following points:

$$J(1,1,0)\;,\;\;H(0,2,2)\;,\;\;I(2,0,1)$$

and thus we get the vectors (fixed at point $\;I\;$ ):

$$\vec{JH}=H-I=(-1,1,2)\;,\;\;\vec{JI}=(1,-1,1)$$

and from here we get at once

$$\vec{JH}\cdot\vec{JI}=(-1,1,2)\cdot(1,-1,1)=-1-1+2=0\implies\vec{JH}\perp\vec{JI}$$

and we're done.

Comment: I thought it was the algebraic method already found by the OP but maybe he/she was referring to something different.

Comment: @gimusi It could be the OP meant this, though for me this'd be more like algebraic-geometric. Not sure...

Comment: Yes indeed I’ve asked the OP for a clarification, in sny case your solution is very nice!

Answer (score 2):

With

\begin{align}
OH &= (0,1,1) \\
OJ &= (1/2, 1/2, 0) \\
OI &= (1, 0, 1/2)
\end{align}
and scaling to a unit cube, then
\begin{align}
JH\cdot JI &= (OH-OJ)\cdot (OI-OJ) \\
&= (-1/2, 1/2, 1) \cdot (1/2, -1/2, 1/2) \\
&= -1/4 -1/4 +1/2 \\
&= 0
\end{align}
so both vectors are perpendicular.

Comment: As noticed for the other solution I thought it was the algebraic method already found by the OP but maybe he/she was referring to something different. I’ve ssked for a clarification on that. Nice solution in any case.

Comment: This is analytic geometry.

Comment: Yes I agree, it seems that the OP used Pythagoras!

Answer (score 1):

Indicating with

- $L$ the side length of the cube
- $d=\sqrt 2 L$ the diagonal of a face
- $\theta_1= \angle DJH$
- $\theta_2= \angle BJI$

we have that

$$\tan \theta_1=\frac{2L}{d}=\sqrt 2 \implies \theta_1=\arctan (\sqrt 2) $$

$$\tan \theta_2=\frac{L}{d}=\frac1{\sqrt 2} \implies \theta_2=\arctan \left(\frac1{\sqrt 2}\right ) $$

therefore the required angle is

$$\pi-(\theta_1+\theta_2)=\frac{\pi}2$$

indeed recall that for $x>0$

$$\arctan x=\frac{\pi}2-\arctan \frac1x$$

Comment: Maybe you should say what $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ are...

Comment: @amsmath Yes of course I just was adding that information, Thanks!

Comment: Thank you, your answer gives me more insight on how to prove the angle. :)

Answer (score 0):

The right triangles $\triangle IJB$ and $\triangle HDJ$ are similar since $HD \times IB=1/2=JB \times JD$. So $\angle HJD + \angle IJB=90$ which implies the claim.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the other excellent answers, here's a more geometric solution. Consider that the plane in which the angle $HJI$ lies looks as follows:

[(Image not to scale)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXaMH.png)

Moreover, the line $IJ$ is parallel to the line $FD$, so the angle $HJI$ is the same as the angle $HXF$.

Because the sides of the rectangle $BDHF$ have a ratio of $1:\sqrt{2}$ the triangles $BDF$ and $DHJ$ are similar. It follows that also the triangles $DHJ$ and $XDJ$ are similar, as they have two angles in common. This shows that the angle $DXJ$ is $90°$, hence so is the angle $HXF$, hence so is the angle $HJI$.

Comment: I don't understand what you call $\;X\;$ to, but no doubt $\;IJ\;$ is **not** parallel to CD...unless "parallel" for you is the same as non-intersecting, which would be odd according to my definitions.

Comment: @DonAntonio Oops, all my $C$' should be $F$'s, I'll edit right away! I call $X$ the intersection of the lines $HJ$ and $DF$, see the linked image.

Comment: I'm not sure HJ and DF intersect... DF is one of the cube's diagonals, HJ is **not** .

Comment: @DonAntonio They are both in the plane $BDHF$, because $J$ is on $BD$ because it is the midpoint of the 'opposite' diagonal $AC$. See the linked picture also.

Comment: As an aside, I see now that Marco's answer is a far simpler solution in the same spirit as mine.

Comment: I think in the last one you're right. I mistook H by K, because of that diagram...

Answer (score 0):

Assume the egde length of the cubic be $a$. We may readily obtain $$HJ^2=HA^2-AJ^2=(\sqrt{2}a)^2-\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}a}{2}\right)^2=\frac{3}{2}a^2;$$$$IJ^2=AI^2-AJ^2=AB^2+BI^2-AJ^2=a^2+\left(\frac{a}{2}\right)^2-\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}a}{2}\right)^2=\frac{3}{4}a^2;$$
$$HI^2=HF^2+FI^2=(\sqrt{2}a)^2+\left(\frac{a}{2}\right)^2=\frac{9}{4}a^2.$$
Therefore $$HJ^2+IJ^2=HI^2,$$ which implies $\angle HJI=90^o.$